# ContextLoader-Context-initilization-failed

Tags: spring-boot

[ERROR] 17:23:17 ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'blPersistenceUnitManager' while setting bean property 'persistenceUnitManager';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blPersistenceUnitManager': Injection of resource dependencies failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: